# Transparency bug in PhotoImage

Tags: python, tkinter

I have two pieces of code, both of them should create test.png containing a black square. The first one does it, but the second returns a transparent square. The difference between them is that the first one has a clear stripe at the left and the second does not.

The first example:

```
root = Tk()
image = PhotoImage(width = 50, height = 50)
for x in range(1, 50):
    for y in range(50):
        pixel(image, (x,y), (0,0,0))
image.write('test.png', format='png')
```

The second example:

```
root = Tk()
image = PhotoImage(width = 50, height = 50)
for x in range(50):
    for y in range(50):
        pixel(image, (x,y), (0,0,0))
image.write('test.png', format='png')
```

I also import tkinter and use function pixel(), which has this code:

```
def pixel(image, pos, color):
    """Place pixel at pos=(x,y) on image, with color=(r,g,b)."""
    r,g,b = color
    x,y = pos
    image.put("#%02x%02x%02x" % (r,g,b), (x, y))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it short: Tkinter's `PhotoImage` class can't really save PNGs. It does only support GIF, PGM and PPM. You may have noticed that the preview image is correctly colored, but when you open the file, it's blank.

To save PNG images, you have to use the Python Imaging Library or, for Python 3, [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow).
With this, the image creation is even easier:

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.new("RGB", (50, 50), (0,0,0))
image.save('test.png', format='PNG')
```

If you need, you can convert it to PIL's `ImageTk.PhotoImage` object that can be used in Tkinter.